# Installing an app after deleting its apk using Bloatware removal tool

Tags: insufficient-memory, bloatware

I'm working on Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow. It's unrooted.

My phone has a lot of apps preinstalled that I don't use, like Google Play music and movies and TV. I want to remove these apps **completely** as they use up a lot of space on my phone'so internal memory.

I found [here](https://missingtricks.net/uninstall-system-apps-android-without-root/) a tutorial on how I can remove such bloatware without rooting my phone. However,  my question is: if I completely remove the app files from my phone, then will I be able to install them later, if need arises?

For example, in my phone, MS Word and Excel are preinstalled, which is why I can't move them to sd card. If I remove the apk files, and later try to install it again, will I face any trouble, and will I be able to move it to the sd card?

*N.B.: I don't want to root my phone.*

Comment: For most apps, yes, but a few Google Apps would still require installing to `/system`.

Comment: @AndyYan I don't want those google apps. I want the MS apps such that they can be moved to sd card. Does the software in the tutorial completely remove the apk files?

Comment: Just checked it out - without root nothing could touch `/system`, it just disables the apps (similar to `pm disable` I reckon).

Comment: @AndyYan is rooting good for phone?

Comment: @AndyYan if yes, which software will be best? I want to unroot it again. I had used Kingo root on a phone before, but couldn't unroot it.